# Increase the width of the text box made by bsPopover in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Friends, I would like to increase the width of the text box made by bsPopover. Make it more horizontal, that is, increase the width of the text box. It's possible?? The executable code is below. Any help is appreciated.

```
library(shinyBS)
library(shiny)


DES_filter1<-paste("Sudden she seeing garret far regard. By hardly it direct if pretty up regret. Ability thought enquire settled prudent you sir. Or easy knew sold on well come year. Something consulted age extremely end procuring. Collecting preference he inquietude projection me in by. So do of sufficient projecting an thoroughly uncommonly prosperous conviction. Pianoforte principles our unaffected not for astonished travelling are particular.", sep = "<br>")


ui <- fluidPage(


  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      radioButtons(
        "filter1", 
        h3("Select properties"), 
        choiceValues = c(1, 2),
        choiceNames = list(
          tagList(
            tags$span("All properties"),
            tags$span(icon("info-circle"), id = "icon1", style = "color: blue;")
          ), 
          tagList(
            tags$span("Exclude properties"),
            tags$span(icon("info-circle"), id = "icon2", style = "color: blue;")
          )
        ),
        selected = 1
      ),

      bsPopover("icon1", "TITLE1", DES_filter1, placement = "right"), 
      bsPopover("icon2", "TITLE2", "CONTENT2", placement = "right"), 

      radioButtons("filter2", h3("Select farms"),
                   choices = list("All farms" = 1, 
                                  "Exclude farms" = 2),
                   selected = 1),
      ),

    mainPanel(

    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you very much friends!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(shinyBS)
library(shiny)

popoverTempate <- 
  '<div class="popover popover-lg" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>'

DES_filter1<-paste("Sudden she seeing garret far regard. By hardly it direct if pretty up regret. Ability thought enquire settled prudent you sir. Or easy knew sold on well come year. Something consulted age extremely end procuring. Collecting preference he inquietude projection me in by. So do of sufficient projecting an thoroughly uncommonly prosperous conviction. Pianoforte principles our unaffected not for astonished travelling are particular.", sep = "<br>")


ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(".popover.popover-lg {width: 500px; max-width: 500px;}"))
  ),
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      radioButtons(
        "filter1", 
        h3("Select properties"), 
        choiceValues = c(1, 2),
        choiceNames = list(
          tagList(
            tags$span("All properties"),
            tags$span(icon("info-circle"), id = "icon1", style = "color: blue;")
          ), 
          tagList(
            tags$span("Exclude properties"),
            tags$span(icon("info-circle"), id = "icon2", style = "color: blue;")
          )
        ),
        selected = 1
      ),

      bsPopover("icon1", "TITLE1", DES_filter1, placement = "right", 
                options = list(template = popoverTempate)), 
      bsPopover("icon2", "TITLE2", "CONTENT2", placement = "right"), 

      radioButtons("filter2", h3("Select farms"),
                   choices = list("All farms" = 1, 
                                  "Exclude farms" = 2),
                   selected = 1),
    ),

    mainPanel(

    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience Stephane, but if possible you could take a look at these two issues?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61782359/change-the-color-tone-of-a-shinytheme?noredirect=1#comment109280506_61782359
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61785303/insert-figure-in-shiny-navbarpage

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, you could take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62598389/insert-bspopover-in-shiny  It is similar.